# Framework7 search bar and virtual list

Tags: android, ios, mobile, html-framework-7

I'm starting to move on framework7 and I have some problems, even following the examples of the site, to stay with the same base.

What I want is that when there is a search go to an api and return the results to a list.

What already have:

```
var myList = app.virtualList('.searchbar-found', {
    items: [],
    template: '<li class="item-content">' +
                '<div class="item-inner">' +
                    '<div class="item-title">{{title}}</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</li>',
});
var searchBar = app.searchbar('.searchbar', {
    customSearch: true,
    onSearch: function(string){
        if(!string.query) {
            console.log('deleteAllItems');
            myList.deleteAllItems();
            return ;
        }
        var request = $$.ajax({
            url: 'http://app/dist/server.php?q='+string.query,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "json",
            statusCode: {
                200: function(xhr){
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
                    console.log(response.records);
                    var result = []; 
                    $$.each(response.records, function (index, value) {
                        result.push({
                            title: value.title,
                            nif: value.nif
                        });
                    });

                    myList.prependItems(result);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What happens now with this code is that it always search with the list that comes from the last letter typed ... for example: 'Yes' does not appear results, but if you delete the last letter already appears...

Help? :/